# Filters that allows for comparison of model properties

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

Using loopback where filter would be a lot more versatile if you could do queries that relate the model's instance properties to one another:

```
{
  where: {
    modelId: id,
    someProp: {
      neq: {
        property: someOtherProp
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The neq I'm referencing denotes 'not equal' .. eg. someProp != someOtherProp or 'bigger' someProp > someOtherProp .

Right now, If i want to compare 2 properties I need to go to SQL and do a manual query there. Can this be a feature for future release?

Comment: Would indeed love to see that as a feature.